# how to view turbo c++ fullscreen? (windows 7 32-bit)

Tags: turbo-c++

I am using windows 7 OS (32 bit). I have installed Turbo c++ IDE on my system. It is running properly. But the problem I faced is that its not in the fullscreen mode. I pressed `Alt+Enter` still there is no use and a message

> this system does not support fullscreen mode is displayed.

How can I change the size (increase).

Comment: I think you need to install MSDOS 6.22 from three floppy disks and then run Turbo C++ with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [this](http://turboc7.blogspot.in/2011/11/run-full-screen-turbo-c-in-windows-78.html)  for the same . Or you can methods noted [here](http://www.infolet.org/2012/10/how-to-get-turbo-cc-in-full-screen-on.html). BTW [DosBox](http://itankur.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/how-to-ru-turbo-c-in-windows-7-in-full-screen/) is a good choice .

Comment: the methods noted does not make the screen fullscreen. it just enlarged. and the number of lines displayed also does not change... I dont have an option in my workstation to switch to other IDE.

Comment: DosBox does allow fullscreen.

Answer (score 2):

Broland has not released any version of Turbo C or C++ that is compatible with Windows 7 or Windows 8. But there are third party Turbo C++ compilers that works fine on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

After searching hrs on google i found

The best of turbo c emulater that is C++ by yogisoft

Download it from http://www.turboc8.com/p/download.html

Works for all 32 & 64 bit Windows 8,7,xp and vista. 
Full Screen Enabled!!!

This is All in one solution

Gyzs go for it...
Source(s):
http://www.turboc8.com

Answer (score 0):

Run Turboc C, Ignore the warning now open properties of turboc c windows and make these changes

Font Lucida Console
Font Size 28

Layout

Screen Buffer size 80 X 28 (W X H)
Windows Size 80 X 28 (W X H)
Windows Position -4 -4 (Left & Top)
Uncheck the box of (Let System Position the Window) n enjoy full screen...

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Just disable graphics driver you computer from device manager and enjoy turbo c++ in full screen mode like XP.

DosBox is not a complete solution. It hangs mouse after some time in windows 7.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

when you are using console view always use it for full screen Alt+Enter.